# Is there a python data structure that is: keyed, ordered, and addressable via key and order?

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure that's a mix of OrderedDict but also addressable via an integer, depending on when the element was added.

i.e.

```
config_key = OrderedDict([('Version_Number', 'a'),
                ('Hardware_Config', 'b'),
                ('Size_Of_Data', 'c'),
                ('Checksum', 'd')])
```

That will function like:

```
>> print config_key['Version_Number']
a
>> print config_key[0]
a
>> print config_key['Size_Of_Data']
c
>> print config_key[2]
c
>> for x in config_key:
>>  print x
Version_Number
Hardware_Config
Size_Of_Data
Checksum
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.7+ then there's one built in.

http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

*edit:* So it looks like the order of items is supported via pop operations, but you could do the equivalent of what you want via `list(my_ordered_dict)[i]` where `i` is an integer.

```
# Make your own like this...
class CustomOrderedDict(collections.OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        try:
            return self.values()[key]
        except TypeError:
            return super(CustomOrderedDict,self).__getitem__(key)
```

*edits:*

(Sorry about all these bugs, I just typed it up real quick to give you an idea of what to do.)

- fixed returning values instead of key
- fixed recursion flub
- switched list access to `[]` syntax, since, being a list, that makes more sense.

Comment: My experience with OrderedDict is that it isn't addressable via order an element as added.

i.e. From the example above, this wouldn't work:
>> print config_key[0]

Comment: That edit got it working.

Somewhat inelegantly:
config_key[list(config_key)[i]]
...but I'll take it.

Comment: Incredibly sexy inherited member function. Thanks!

Comment: Very wasteful though - creating a new list every time. (And is there a reason you use `.__getitem(key)` over `[key]`?)

Comment: This doesn't work. `__getitem__()` calls itself recursively when the `key` isn't an `int`. Also, type checking isn't very "Pythonic" (or object-oriented).

Comment: Ignoring the recursion problem, the values returned when `key` is an `int` is the *key* at the position not the corresponding value there. So `config_key[0]` would result in `Version_Number` not `a`.

Comment: @martineau whoops, the recursion thing is a bug; I agree with your second point, but in fairness that is essentially what the OP asked for.

Comment: @martineau with regards to your second comment, thanks, I believe I fixed that in an edit.

Comment: @Chris W.: Much better, however you only need a `return self.values()[key]` when `key` is an `int` (since `self.values()` returns a `list`). May I also suggest removing the type check and using a `try/except`.

Comment: @Chris W.: P.S. Getting rid of the unneeded `list()` and just using a plain `self.values()` should also nullify @delnan's comment about it being very wasteful since it will be using the list that the base class OrderedDict likely already maintains internally.

Comment: +1 with the fixes and improvements. One might want to reverse the order what's attempted first in the `try/except` depending on which kind of usage is the more common.